# After adding a .jar file to a project in netbeans, how do I import classes in it to my project in netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

I have made the jar file with `.class` files.  Now, i want include `classes` from but it's giving me an `error`, How to resolve this issue?

[image]

Comment: Click on the little [+] next to the Jar and make sure that it actually contains the the classes you are expecting.  Try performing a clean and build.  If all else fails, you might need to delete the cache and perform another clean and build

Comment: It does contain all the classes in a folder called `org.everything` inside the alib.jar library. But to use the classes, do you just import it the way I did or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I though the `import` should be the package name the classes are coming from `org.everything`...

Comment: [Check this image](http://s18.postimg.org/flihen5uh/err2.png). This is the directory structure. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Nope defiantly `import org.eveything` - the name of the library/jar file is irrelevent

Comment: It still shows an error. Red underline under the `org` part in `import org.everything.*`.

Comment: Have you tried using [ctrl]+[shift]+[i] to fix importants?  You may need to delete the cache and try again

Comment: I tried deleting the cache too, it doesn't work.

Comment: Remove the jar and try re-adding it.  If that doesn't work, try creating a new projecting and adding it to that to see if works.  If all else fails either download a new version or re-build it.  Also make sure that the class files are compiled for the same verion of java that your project is using...ie don't use classes from Java 7 with Java 6

Answer (score 2):

Based on this information...

[image: Err]

The import statement should be `import org.everything.*`.  The jar/library name is irrlevent, your only interested in the package names